# directionalLayoutMargins on UIImageView not working inside horizontal stack view

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I am creating a horizontal stack view:

```
let hs = UIStackView(forAutoLayout: ());
hs.axis = .horizontal
hs.spacing = 0
hs.alignment = .top
hs.distribution = .fill
hs.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
hs.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
hs.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

And then placing a couple children:

```
let label = UILabel(forAutoLayout: ());
hs.addArrangedSubview(label)
let image = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 32, height: 32))
image.directionalLayoutMargins = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 64, leading: 0, bottom: 16, trailing: 16)
hs.addArrangedSubview(image)
```

The horizontal stack view layout looks right, however I added a layout margin to the image that seems to be ignored.  Is there a way to set a margin around specific children in a horizontal stack view?

**EDIT:**

I get that I can throw the UIImageView inside another view and setup constraints.  Or even easier just throw it in another stack view with EdgeInsets:

```
let imageStack = UIStackView(forAutoLayout: ());
imageStack.axis = .vertical
imageStack.alignment = .fill
imageStack.distribution = .fill
imageStack.directionalLayoutMargins = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 64, leading: 0, bottom: 16, trailing: 16)
imageStack.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
imageStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

imageStack.addArrangedSubview(image)

// add imageStack to horizontal stack view, instead of image
hs.addArrangedSubview(imageStack)
```

Adding to another view or playing with the image rect insets inside the UIImageView seems like overkill just to add margin or padding around a view.  Coming from Android where I can just set padding and margin on any view including image views without wrapping in another element this just seems like a crazy amount of work for something so simple.

Comment: Are you trying to "add top padding" to the image view? If so, that approach is incorrect. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551890/how-to-add-leading-padding-to-view-added-inside-an-uistackview

Comment: So to add insets or margin to an imageview you have to put it in another view.  Seems ridiculous, thanks iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Not *entirely* sure what you're going for, but it sounds like you want:

- horizontal stack view
- label on the left
- image view on the right
- image view 32x32 its
- image view top 64-pts from the label top

So, it would look like this:

[image]

The green outlines are showing the element frames (including the stack view).

If that's correct, you can do this by using `.withAlignmentRectInsets()` to modify the image at run-time.

Here's an example:

```
class StackTestViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let hs = UIStackView()
    let label = UILabel()
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        hs.axis = .horizontal
        hs.spacing = 0
        hs.alignment = .top
        hs.distribution = .fill
        hs.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        hs.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        label.text = "Test Label"
        
        hs.addArrangedSubview(label)
        hs.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
        
        view.addSubview(hs)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            hs.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 80.0),
            hs.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            
            imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32.0),
            
            // we want the imageView to be 64-pts taller than its width
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.widthAnchor, constant: 64)
            
        ])
        
        if let img = UIImage(named: "swiftBlue64x64") {
            // use withAlignmentRectInsets to create a new image with 64-pts "empty space" on top
            imageView.image = img.withAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: -64, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0))
        }

        // so we can see the label frame
        label.backgroundColor = .yellow
        
    }
    
}
```

I used this 64x64 pixel image:

[image]

---

**Edit**

From Apple's docs:

> **Discussion**
>
> Use this property to specify the desired amount of space (measured in points) between the edges of this view and its subviews.

So, you can either apply that to a `UIStackView` *as a whole* or to a view that has subviews. Which should explain why it cannot be applied to a `UIImageView` (no subviews).

Comment: Thank you.  I updated the question, I suppose its really about a misunderstanding I think I had with directionalLayoutMargins.  Seems like I should be able to just set margins on the ImageView.  I get that I can wrap the UIIImageView in another view, or mess with the image insets inside the ImageView.  But that seems like a workaround for the fact that one cannot just simply add margin around an ImageView.